# Regular expression to find event handlers in a big .cs file

Tags: c#, .net, regex, visual-studio-2012

(VS2012 C#) I have a big .cs file with no regions and no structure. Using "Find and replace" tool I want to find out all event handlers like: button_Click, window_Loaded, etc. So it has format: text1_text2, which text1 and text2 must exist (has min length 1) and separated by underscore _.
How is the regular expression?

Thank you in advance.

Mag
PS: Till now I never use "the mighty" regular expression, because I didn't need it, but now it's time for me to use it. Of course, before I ask here I have tried to read the online help of vs2012 and tried many times, but failed.

Comment: are you 100% sure they all follow that pattern. That's the default that .net creates when you double click an event, but there's nothing to stop someone writing them without underscores. or writing regular methods with underscores.

Comment: To frighten you further, there are lambdas and anonymous functions in the .net world now! :)

Comment: Might be worth editing the file in another editor since Visual Studio is a bit weird with its Regex syntax (e.g. Notepad++).

Comment: @Septih VS2012 supports regexes, .NET flavor, properly now (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @Eoin Campbell: yes I am sure since the developer follows strictly a coding guideline of his enterprise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
([a-z_]\w*)_([a-z\d]+)
```

Matches:

> Some_Button1_Click
>
> Button1_Click
>
> Some_strange_Button1_Click

Sample code:

```
const string strRegex = @"([a-z_]\w*)_([a-z\d]+)";
const RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
string text = @"Some_Button1_Click";

var matches = myRegex.Matches(text)
              .Cast<Match>()
              .Select(x => new {
                      AllText = x.Groups[0],  // all text      ==> "Some_Button1_Click"
                      Object = x.Groups[1],   // ([a-z_]\w*)   ==> "Some_Button1"
                      Event = x.Groups[2]     // ([a-z\d]+)    ==> "Click"
                  })
              .ToList();
```

Comment: thx for creditably answer especially with sample code! I just need to add the numeric 0-9.

Comment: @MagB: `\d` represents a digit in regular expressions - see [Regular Expression Language - Quick Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)

Comment: @MagB: ...and `\w` matches letters, digits and underscores

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z]+
```

But you can search for `object sender` and `EventArgs e` too if the event handlers are generated.

Comment: do we need to escape `_` ?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be needed. In classic regex it is not a special character, and the VS IDE Find&Replace Regex doesn't treat it specially either

Comment: "object sender" works like a charm. "EventArgs e" works equally well.

Comment: @Dialecticus: make it an answer, it is very handy one.

Comment: @Matten: thx. using "object sender" is a good and simple idea, but "EventArgs e" is not always good since there is also for example "PropertyChangedEventArgs e"

Comment: @MagB yes, which ends with "EventArgs e"

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub {[A-Za-z0-9]+}\_{[A-Za-z0-9]+}
```

Remember that you'll need these curly braces if you're using the regex in Visual Studio and if you need the Replace function too. The terms `\1`, `\2` in the Replace text will then refer to the corresponding captured group identified by the curly braces in Find text.

Comment: Edited, for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?i)[a-z0-9]+\_[a-z]+
```

This should work, it will find a letter 1 or more times `[a-z]+` then an underscore `\_` then the same again `[a-z]+`. `(?i)` makes it case insensitive so the letters will be found wether capital or not.

Comment: i believe the first part could contain 0-9 (as in button1_Click)